# Jetty Websocket connection - ignore self signed certs

Tags: java, ssl, websocket

Is there a way (other than opening a browser and accepting the self signed certificate) to tell Jetty WebSockets to ignore self signed certificate errors when opening websocket connections? I have verified my code works in an environment where a valid certificate exists, so this is definately related to using self signed certs in other environments.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String destUri = "wss://example.ws.uri.com";
    if (args.length > 0) {
        destUri = args[0];
    }


    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(sslContextFactory);
    SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();
    try {
        client.start();
        URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
        ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);
        System.out.printf("Connecting to : %s%n", echoUri);
        socket.awaitClose(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just tell SslContextFactory to not validate certificates

```
SslContextFactory sec = new SslContextFactory();
sec.setValidateCerts(false);
```